# Java HashSet Optimization

Tags: java, hash, hashset

**How is the HashSet class in Java implemented so that it runs efficiently?**

---

On an assignment, I was asked to implemented a data structure similar to a HashSet from scratch.

The basic concept was to use an array of LinkedList, resizing when the load factor -- *L = N / S*, where *L* is the load factor, *N* the total number of elements, and *S* the size of the array -- exceeded some constant.

In the function to resize, I tried to solely use functions within the LinkedList class that were of O(1) when recomputing the hashcode of each element and reinserting into the HashSet.

In the hashcode function itself, I simply referred to using the hashcode for the String class, modulo'd with the array size to prevent an 'index out of bounds' exception.

With this implementation, I am still not able to achieve half the performance as achieved by the HashSet class provided by Java.

I am leaning to believe that it is hashcode within the class that makes it so efficient: one that would evenly distribute the input, whether it was ordered or not, such that the size of array needed would be *S = N / C* -- where *S* is the size of the array, *N* the number of elements, and *C* be some small integer constant such that searching through a LinkedList would be O(C).

If so, or if not, how does the hashcode or HashSet work?

Comment: You can see for yourself (`HashMap` is used internally by `HashSet`) http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java?av=f

Comment: Also for a school assignment, your implementation should not reasonably be expected to perform as well as the `java.util` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm is called seperatechaining,There is [[book]](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/)which is studied and you can find here it's details. When you resize the array, don't try to move the entries from one list to temporary and then back to that list. You can simple let list refer to the temporary list.

Comment: Hm, so are you saying I should not be popping out the LinkedList and rehashing its elements?

Comment: There are many possible options, Suppose you have an array of $10$ elements and each array entry has one linkedlist. Depending on the type of keys you are using once again suppose that your first $1000$ entries fall into only 5 buckets which means that you have $5$ linkedList of 200 elements and some later time you 6th element and you need to increase size.

Comment: At this point you are computing 200 hashfunctions for each of the linked list and in total $1000$  which will take a lot of time. You can only compute new function of the one element from each list and add this element in a new linkedlist , since the head of this linked is an element of previous ,you can let tail point to the previous linkedlist because all those values will hash to same bucket as this element because they were previously in same bucket.